# python script to get the IAM users list who has not logged in for 60 days

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I want to run a script which will pullout the details of the IAM users who has not logged in to the AWS console for 60 days by comparing the current date.
 i have tried this script and getting error as

> "TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime".

Kindly help me in resolving this error and verify my code.

```
import boto3
import datetime
resource = boto3.resource('iam')
client = boto3.client("iam")
for user in resource.users.all():
      if user.password_last_used is not None:
            last_login = datetime.datetime.strptime(user.password_last_used, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            print("Username: ",[user.user_name], current_date-last_login)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `strptime` to accomplish this.  Try this out:

```
import boto3
import datetime
from dateutil.tz import tzutc

resource = boto3.resource('iam')
client = boto3.client("iam")

today = datetime.datetime.now()

for user in resource.users.all():
    if user.password_last_used is not None:
        delta = (today - user.password_last_used.replace(tzinfo=None)).days
        if delta >= 60:
            print("Username: ",[user.user_name], delta)
```

The AWS API returns the time for the passwords last use with a timezone.  The `replace` command removes it and then the magic happens.

Comment: one more help "I need user list who has not logged in more than 60 days from today date,remaining users should be excluded "

Comment: @ArunkumarMurthy I updated the answer to reflect your request.  If things are working as expected you can accept the answer